# Git pushing old commits from deleted files

Tags: git, github, push, git-commit, git-push

I keep trying to push a brand new repository and a brand new branch. When I do so, it pushes files and commits from weeks ago. These files were deleted a while ago. There's absolutely nothing in my working tree, my source control is empty. I'm not understanding how I can get this behavior to stop because it keeps happening. I search for things online, and I don't see anyone else that has this problem. Any suggestions???

Comment: Are the files in the *history* of the branch you are pushing?

Comment: @TTT thanks for responding. I don't think so. I'm looking at my source control and the only changes are for my current branch, current file I'm looking in. Nothing else. Is there another way to check the history?

Answer (score 0):

I recognize my error. I need to do a `git init` first, then `git add .` then `git commit -m "initial commit"` then do a `git push --set-upstream origin master`. This then pushes only the folder/project I want to github.

Comment: Don't put repositories inside other repositories. Because if you were able to push, that means you are _already_ inside another repository. Don't nest them, unless you really know what you are doing